# Triple boot with Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10 and SuSE Leap, can't see partitions during installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a system with Windows 10 and Suse Leap 42.1 already installed and running.  Ubuntu's installer running from a DVD has very limited partitioning flexibility.  I created two Ext4 partitions using SuSE but Ubuntu won't recognize them.  It will only allow Ubuntu to use the entire disk.

Will a Ubuntu 16.04 Live CD allow me to use the new empty partitions and, if so, how do I create a 16.04 Live cd/dvd?  The only references I've seen for live cds relate to earlier versions of Ubuntu.

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 installed on a 2nd PC.  Can I use it to create a Live cd?

**Update:**
I made the boot USB device but the Ubuntu partitioner on it was the same as on the install DVD.  I have two hard drives in my machine, both with multiple partitions.  The Ubuntu partitioner recognizes the partitions on my #2 drive but shows no partitions on my #1 (Windows boot) drive.  This is in the "Something Else" in the install partition routine.  I don't want to create new partitions on the boot drive fearing that it will destroy my Windows 10 folders.  Something that may confuse the Ubuntu installer is that I have SUSE Leap 42.1 installed on my #2 HD.  I'd like to have access to both distros.  Would another Linux distro offer a more robust HD installation tool?

Comment: If during the partitioning portion of the install, you select "Something else", do you see all the partitions?

Comment: If you left Windows fast startup on, that is hibernation. And the Linux NTFS driver will not mount your NTFS if it is hibernated or needs chkdsk.  It  needs chkdsk after a resize. Or if you have something special on that drive. If not the  Windows issues post this: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 16.04 Live usb on your windows 10 Partition by using a program called Rufus and an Ubuntu 16.04 iso:

**Rufus Download** (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjQ5teN3aXNAhXJVhoKHRymCU8QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Frufus.akeo.ie%2F&usg=AFQjCNGeuqrM--4SkP8QoxA61Q4KwAEIHQ&sig2=wnUHRR-9bNV1T_Ofi64bVw)

**Ubuntu 16.04 Download** (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=16.04&architecture=amd64)

**Steps to install:**

- make the live usb by following the steps on the rufus website (if you need further assistance dont hesitate to ask)
- reboot your PC and boot to the flash disk

(once youre in the Ubuntu install menu:)

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Select if you want or just click continue
3. Click "Something Else"
4. Find the empty partition you allocated to Ubuntu
5. Define the root file system

The OS should install and appear on the grub menu. If this does not work you could try deleting the partition leaving it as "free space" and formatting it withing the live installation menu.

Hope this helps

Comment: I made the boot USB device but the Ubuntu partitioner on it was the same as on the install DVD.  I have two hard drives in my machine, both with multiple partitions.  The Ubuntu partitioner recognizes the partitions on my #2 drive but shows no partitions on my #1 (Windows boot) drive.  This is the "Something Else" in the install partition routine.  I don't want to create new partitions on the boot drive fearing that it will destroy my Windows 10 folders.  Something that may confuse the Ubuntu installer is that I have SUSE Leap 42.1 installed on my #2 HD.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have written you have two possibilities: you can resize the windows10 partition without affecting your data going to the settings menu, you have to set that partition as unformatted and Ubuntu should see it, at least this happened to me. The other option is to do the same using gparted or similar under openSuse. 
When you install Ubuntu you should select the voice manually manage partitions or similar. 
If it fits your needs I would suggest to share the home folder of openSuse with Linux...